# what is the meaning of "should never" and "should not" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "should never" and "should not" in this context?

> There are one or two points about the case which would bear
>   discussion. One is that a man with so remarkable a name as Charles B.
>   Rosma **should never have been traced**, considering all the publicity
>   which the case acquired. This would certainly at the time have
>   appeared a formidable objection, but with our fuller knowledge we
>   appreciate how very difficult it is to get names correctly across. A
>   name apparently is a purely conventional thing, and as such very
>   different from an idea. Every practising Spiritualist has received
>   messages which were correct coupled with names which were mistaken. It
>   is possible that the real name was Ross, or possibly Rosmer, and that
>   this error prevented identification. Again, it is curious that he
>   **should not have known** that his body had been moved from the centre of the cellar to the wall, where it was eventually found. We can only
>   record the fact without attempting to explain it.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Does your language not have not and never?

Answer (score 1):

He should = He is supposed to
He shouldn't = He is not supposed to

He should have = He was supposed to
He shouldn't have = He was not supposed to
*(the past tense of "should" is "should have")*

Using "never" after "should" in negative statements is for emphasis , you can use "not" instead .

**He should never have been traced** = He was not supposed to be traced.

**He should not have known** = He was not supposed to know.

Comment: This is wrong, as it assumes that _should_ has deontic meaning, but actually both _shoulds_ are epistemic. See my answer. (I wasn't sure about this for a moment, because _supposed_ can also have an epistemic meaning; but it is uncommon in the negative).

Comment: @Colin Fine I remember trying to put things into perspective for the asker according to my understanding of *should have* but it seems that *to suppose* was not the best verb to use. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both these uses of *should* are [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) (about the speaker's knowledge and expectations), not deontic (about obligations).
In these examples, the "should" expresses something like surprise. A paraphrase of the first is "I am surprised that somebody with such a remarkable name was not traced".

Similarly the second one expresses something like "It is surprising that he did not know".

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The two phrases have similar meanings here.

'Should never have been traced', in this context means that the man was not traced.

> One is that a man with so remarkable a name as Charles B. Rosma was not traced, considering all the publicity which the case acquired.

'Should not have known', means that he didn't know.

> It was curious (strange) that he didn't know that his body had been moved.

This is a subjunctive form and is an obsolete usage in contemporary American English. It was more common prior to the 20th century than now.

See [English Language on Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336434/why-is-should-put-in-the-following-sentences) for more explanation.